# django login takes 1 arguments instead of 2

Tags: django, authentication, arguments

i get this error when trying to use the 'login()'

```
login() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Now i use this to handle my userlogin, and im pretty sure it worked before i copied it. tho now it tells me i give 2 arguments except 1.

my login view:

```
def login(request):
    """Logs a user into the application."""

    auth_form = AuthenticationForm(None, request.POST or None)
    # The form itself handles authentication and checking to make sure passowrd and such are supplied.
    if auth_form.is_valid():
        login(request, auth_form.get_user())
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'auth_form': auth_form})
```

dont got any idea what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same name `login` as a view name; this shadows the function you want call.

Use a different name for the view.

Or call `login` function with qualified form:

```
django.contrib.auth.login(request, auth_form.get_user())
```

Comment: Thanks completely forgot about that, been sitting on this for some time :)